# Update on Android system (pgfplots)

Tags: pgfplots, update, android

How can I do to update a package such as pgfplots on Android system ?
I usualy write my tex documents using TeX writer.
The tex system files are stored inside /texmf-dist and /texmf-local directories. 
I need to use the newest version of pgfplots but the actual on my system is 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is [here](https://apps.texwriter.net/ios-guide/install.html). Even if it's the IOs page the description is also convenient for Android